# Javascript combine 2 map arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, dictionary

I've got a question about 2 arrays I have. I've been mapping one array into a table.
First array looks like this:

[image]

```
{data.portfolioHoldings.map((portfolioholding) => (
      <tbody key={portfolioholding.id}>
        <tr key={portfolioholding.id}>
          <th scope="row">{portfolioholding.id}</th>
          <td>{portfolioholding.ticker_symbol}</td>
          <td>{portfolioholding.amount}</td>
          <td>{portfolioholding.fees}</td>))}
```

**Which results in a table like this:**
[image]

**However I've got another array (from a different api source):**
[image]

**I'd like to combine these 2 data sources into 1 table . As you can see ID 1 of the second array is 149.03. I'd like to have another < td> behind "fees" that says latest price with the value of ID 1.**

**How can I map both arrays and work together like one?**

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: "ID 1 of the second array" -> I can't see any id in the second array. Did you mean the first element of the second array, which means `array2[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, let's say your second array is named `arr2`, you can do this:

```
{data.portfolioHoldings.map((portfolioholding, index) => (
      <tbody key={portfolioholding.id}>
        <tr key={portfolioholding.id}>
          <th scope="row">{portfolioholding.id}</th>
          <td>{portfolioholding.ticker_symbol}</td>
          <td>{portfolioholding.amount}</td>
          <td>{portfolioholding.fees}</td>))
          <td>{arr2[index].quote.latestPrice}</td>))
}
```

Make sure two arrays have the same length and the second array should always have `quote.latestPrice` inside each element, otherwise, you will encounter errors.

Just a note, seems like your `tbody` should be outside of the `map` function, only one `tbody` is needed for each table

Answer (score 0):

Merged data, something like this ?

```js
let data1 = [
    { id: "1", name: "AAPL", amount: 154, fees: 0.5 },
    { id: "1", name: "AMZN", amount: 3000, fees: 0.5 },
];

let data2 = [
    { id: "1", lastePrice: 149.55 },
    { id: "2", lastePrice: 3475.79 }
];

const allData = (d1, d2) =>
    d1.map(item1 => ({
        ...d2.find((item2) => (item2.id === item1.id) && item2),
        ...item1
    }));

console.log( allData(data1, data2));
```